# Java Rest Service works for a while, then begins failing with multiple root causes for jpa-Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, rest, jpa

As the title says, I have implemented a service that simply updates or creates records in a database. This works for a time, but at some point will return the following stack trace. If we restart the Tomcat9 server, it begins to function as intended. I suspect a memory leak as we've been encountering those in recent months, but usually the stack trace explicitly tells me if the heap has run out.

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    type Exception report

    message org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:419)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    root cause

    org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
        org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
        org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
        org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
        org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
        org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
        javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
        javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
        dao.Fsi_DAO.updateFSIUpdateLogTable(Fsi_DAO.java:1777)
        product.FsiProductLine.updateFSIStatusForSection(FsiProductLine.java:220)
        com.valassis.rest.JSONService.updateFSISectionStatus(JSONService.java:341)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:158)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    root cause

    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
        org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
        org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
        org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
        org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
        org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
        org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
        org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
        javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
        javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
        dao.Fsi_DAO.updateFSIUpdateLogTable(Fsi_DAO.java:1777)
        product.FsiProductLine.updateFSIStatusForSection(FsiProductLine.java:220)
        com.valassis.rest.JSONService.updateFSISectionStatus(JSONService.java:341)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:158)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    root cause

    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:ebfc4d86-40d7-4ca8-993b-0bfef00375b4".
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2826)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1829)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2391)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2042)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1889)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1120)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:700)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
        org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
        org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
        org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
        org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
        org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
        org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
        javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
        javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
        dao.Fsi_DAO.updateFSIUpdateLogTable(Fsi_DAO.java:1777)
        product.FsiProductLine.updateFSIStatusForSection(FsiProductLine.java:220)
        com.valassis.rest.JSONService.updateFSISectionStatus(JSONService.java:341)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:158)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    root cause

    java.io.IOException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:ebfc4d86-40d7-4ca8-993b-0bfef00375b4
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:786)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:836)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:829)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:999)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:989)
        sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
        sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
        sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1756)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2391)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2042)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1889)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1120)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:700)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
        org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
        org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
        org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
        org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
        org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
        org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
        org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
        javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
        javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
        dao.Fsi_DAO.updateFSIUpdateLogTable(Fsi_DAO.java:1777)
        product.FsiProductLine.updateFSIStatusForSection(FsiProductLine.java:220)
        com.valassis.rest.JSONService.updateFSISectionStatus(JSONService.java:341)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:158)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="MISTRAL_DEV_PERSISTENCE">
        <description> Hibernate JPA Configuration Example</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://valvcssq028vm\\SQL Server 9.00.5000:1433;databaseName=Mistral_Annex_Dev" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="vb_application" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="developer" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                      value="jdbc:sqlserver://valvcssq028vm\\SQL Server 9.00.5000:1433;databaseName=Mistral_Annex_Dev"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="EIG_DEV_PERSISTENCE">
        <description> Hibernate JPA Configuration Example</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://valvcssq028vm\\SQL Server 9.00.5000.00:1433;databaseName=EIGProduction_Dev" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="vb_application" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="developer" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                      value="jdbc:sqlserver://valvcssq028vm\\SQL Server 9.00.5000:1433;database=EIGProduction_Dev"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: I guess you have created your datasource wrong and after time it gets disconnected from the database and that happens. Give us some code of the configuration and not just the exception

Comment: @VeselinDavidov Included the persistence.xml

Comment: The stack trace looks like your `Fsi_Dao`  constructs a new entityManagerFactory - does that happen on every table access? Don't you re-use your entityManager[Factorie]s?

Comment: @Selaron It does. Should I move the Factory manager creation to a global variable?

Comment: You could provide your source code building and using the entityManager.